# No modules selected. Dart support will be disabled for the project / IntelliJ

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

I got flutter upgarade and imported a project from git.

and I want to run this app but Dart support is disabled.
Flutter SDK path seems apllied but Dart ( on Setting > Languages & Frameworks > Dart seems not be able to be enabled.

How could I solve this situation?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLx4p.png)

Comment: The question is not clear. Did you disable that option for some reason? If not, did you try enabling it and modifying some code in your project in the editor?

Answer (score 4):

Close the project, delete the `.idea` folder and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and checking both boxes would do anything, it would always reset back. My fix is:

- delete the repository
- clone again with terminal (don't use Studio) and set different name for poject: `git clone (url) newName`

And it works.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, you need to set the flag to "Enable Dart support for the following modules"

Comment: The issue persists for me even after having set this flag